# Math calculation in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to perform a simple multiplication in vb.

Below is my code:

```
Dim minus As Integer
Dim minusPrice As Integer
Dim totalPrice As Integer
         If quantity > 20 Then
            minus = quantity - 20
            minusPrice = ((minus) * (0.3))
            MsgBox("Minus " + minus.ToString)
            MsgBox("minusPrice " + minusPrice.ToString)

            totalPrice = 30 + minusPrice
        End If
```

But why is "minusPrice " giving me 0?
It should give me "0.3".

Comment: It depends how `quantity` is initialized. How can we answer your question, if we do not know how much `quantity` is?

Answer (score 7):

You declared minusPrice as an integer, so it has rounded your result.

You need...

```
Dim minusPrice As Decimal
Dim totalPrice As Decimal
```

or Double... or float, depending on your needs.  Prices are usually decimal.

--- Edit ---

Just noticed that I missed a vital part:

```
minusPrice = ((minus) * (0.3m))
```

Unless 0.3 is also expressed as a decimal you may get small rounding errors.

Comment: +1; In addition, from the looks of it `totalPrice` should probably be a decimal too.

Answer (score 3):

`minusPrice` is declared as an `Integer` which will only contain the part before the decimal point. To be able to store decimal values you need to use the type `Decimal`. The same goes for `totalPrice`.

```
Dim minus As Integer
Dim minusPrice As Decimal
Dim totalPrice As Decimal
If quantity > 20 Then
    minus = quantity - 20
    minusPrice = ((minus) * (0.3))
    MsgBox("Minus " + minus.ToString)
    MsgBox("minusPrice " + minusPrice.ToString)

    totalPrice = 30 + minusPrice
End If
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim minusprice as integer
```

this means that when you multiply by .3 you are doing integer multiplication.  The integer part of .3 is 0 so something * 0 = 0.  Change your code to.

```
dim minusprice as single
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared `minusPrice` as `Integer`, it can't contain fractions. The calculation is done correctly, but then it's converted to an integer.

What's happening in the code is actually:

```
minusPrice = CInt(CDbl(minus) * 0.3)
```

If you declare `minusPrice` as a `Double` or `Decimal` instead, the result of the calcuation won't be converted.

The type `Double` is used for regual floating point operations. There is an inherent limitation of precision that you should be aware of, but if you use this just for displaying the price, it's good enough.

The type `Decimal` is a fixed point data type, which means that it can represent fractional values exactly. This is what you should use if you need to keep track of monetary values in a serious way.